# How to create folder to the network computer using os.mkdir() python command on apache?

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, mkdir

I am using Win2008 server + Apache2.2 + mod_python. 
I would make a folder using string value from the web form.
It works in local drive

```
os.mkdir('D:\\temp\\" + folederName)`
```

But it does not work on network -

```
os.mkdir('\\\\192.168.131.200\\temp\\" + folederName)
```

How can I create a folder to the network computer?

Answer (score 2):

Wild Guess:

Mount the Share to a Driveletter, so you can access it via `Z:\xyz.txt`

because the `\\\host\path` ist not really what can be handled in normal filesystem ops.

EDIT: and please use `os.path.join()` instead of hardcoding the path stuff :)